# ReactJS Update a component after log in

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, components

I am trying to update my global application after a user login. I create a separate component in navbar available on every page, the problem is when you log in the current component does not update.

Login component and redux action

```js
export const LOGIN_AUTH = 'LOGIN_AUTH';

export function getAuth(data){

    return dispatch => {

        fetch(`${API_LIVE}api/token-authentication`, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        .then(function (response) {  
            return response.json() 
        }) 
        .then(auth => 
                dispatch(setAuth(auth)) // TO BE UPDATED WITH (register)
        )
        .catch(function (error) {
            dispatch(setAuth('error'))
        });
    }
}



export function setAuth(auth){
    
    return {
        type: LOGIN_AUTH,
        auth
    }
}
```

```js
handleFormLogin( e ){
        
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        let data = {
                        "email": this.refs.email.value,
                        "password": this.refs.password.value
                    };
        this.props.getAuth(data);
        this.props.addWidth();
        window.location.reload();
        setTimeout( () => { 
            this.setState({ loading: false })
            this.setState({ success: true })
        },
        3000);
        this.refs.email.value = '';
        this.refs.password.value = '';
    }

    // Check for error
    componentWillUpdate(nextProps){
        
        if(!nextProps.auth.error){
            localStorage.setItem('token', this.props.auth);
        }else{
            this.setState({ error : true,
                            validateInputEmail: 'red',
                            validateInputPassword: 'red',
                            success: false
                        })
        }

       
    }
```

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    auth: state.authReducer
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getAuth: (data) =>  dispatch(getAuth(data))
    }
}
```

I add a picture for you to see the context more clearly, so basically when I log in I would like for example to update hide/show the button of the component.[image]

If I am calling the state Auth from the other component, the getAuth method seems to be called twice but i just want to get the current state of auth

Other call in external component

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        gallery: state.galleryReducer,
        auth: state
    }
}
```

You can see first dispatch then second dispatch[image]

Comment: so you want the person icon to show/hide based on whether you're logged in or not?

Comment: no the login plugin is updating correctly, but the main component where they is the card need to be updated